# C++ GetCursorPos always returns NULL

Tags: c++, mfc

I'm writing a MFC program and I want to get the selected tree item by using `HitTest()`. Below is part of my code:

```
POINT ptMouse;
GetCursorPos(&ptMouse);
TRACE("x = %f, y = %f\r\n", ptMouse.x, ptMouse.y);
TRACE("Error Code %s\r\n", GetLastError());
m_Tree.ScreenToClient(&ptMouse);
TRACE("x = %f, y = %f\r\n", ptMouse.x, ptMouse.y);
HTREEITEM hTreeSelected = m_Tree.HitTest(ptMouse, 0);
```

It should return a point and map it to the client window. But all I get is `NULL`. The `TRACE` information is as following:

[image]

Is there anyone can tell me what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: Unrelated to your immediate issue, though it seems unusual to call `GetCursorPos` at all. All mouse input messages come with the cursor position, and for everything else you can use [`GetMessagePos`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-getmessagepos) instead. Is this code perhaps not running as part of a message handler?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is that `ptMouse.x` is not a `float`! But `%f` parses a `float`. Replace `%f` with `%d` and it should print a proper value.

For example, this program:

```
#include <Windows.h>
#include <cstdio>

int main() {
    POINT p;
    GetCursorPos(&p);
    printf("\nx: %f\n", p.x);
    printf("\nx: %d\n", p.x);

    return 0;
}
```

Gives this output:

```
x: 0.00000
x: 1325
```

The real value is 1325, of course.

Comment: Also, `GetLastError()` does not return a string, it returns a `DWORD`.  `%s` parses strings, use `%u` instead. It is also possible that the 1st `TRACE` may wipe out the error code, so move the call to `GetLastError()` before both `TRACE`s. Even then, you shouldn't be calling `GetLastError()` at all unless `GetCursorPos()` returns `FALSE`.

Comment: `TRACE`s aside, the original code is fine, in terms of passing `ptMouse` from `GetCursorPos()` to `ScreenToClient()` to `HitTest()`.  So, there is likely something else going on (unless the `TRACE`s are corrupting the `POINT`).